# Excel - Conditional macro / VBA script

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to automate a report that for a customer and I'm a bit stuck with one of the hurdles that needs to overcome, I have some ideas but am new to VB programming.

The requirement is to copy a range of cells from one sheet to another, but the destination needs to change depending on the current date. Using a general example I'm trying to achieve the following:

If the date is the 1st of the month, the destination range is B2:F3, if it is the 2nd then the destination range is B4:F5, if the 3rd then destination is B6:F7....... if the 31st then the destination is B62:F63, the source ranges are static.

I figured I could probably achieve this by writing a huge script which contained an IF statement for each day of the month, but I was hoping I could be a bit smarter and use variables to assign the row references at the beginning of the script then just sub them back into the select/copy statements.

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely you can.

```
Dim x as Integer
Dim daymonth as Integer
Dim rw as String
daymonth = CInt(Format(date, "d"))
x = daymonth * 2
rw = CStr(x)
```

Now you can use range like:

```
Range("D" & rw & ":F" & CStr(x + 1))
```

Just an example. Then since the number is constant between the two ranges just add that number to x and use it in the range.

Comment: Great feedback, both responses pretty much hit the nail on the head. I wasn't sure how if I could integrate a variable into a cell reference and also the usage of methods such as NOW() as opposed to  using a cell to hold this information. This is my first VBA project so sorry for the newbie question.

Answer (score 0):

You may want following subroutine.

```
Sub copyDataDependOnDatte()
  Dim today As Date, dayOfToday As Integer
  Dim sWS As Worksheet, dWS As Worksheet

  'set two worksheets to variables
  Set sWS = Worksheets("source")  'Worksheet which has data to be copied
  Set dWS = Worksheets("destination")  'Worksheet which is used to record data of days.

  ' get day of today
  today = Now()  'get date of today
  dayOfToday = Day(today)  ' get day of today

  Range(sWS.Cells(2, 2), sWS.Cells(3, 6)).Copy 'copy B2:F3 of worksheet "source"
  dWS.Cells(dayOfToday * 2, 2).PasteSpecial ' paste to worksheet "destination" at place determined by day of today

End Sub
```

In this code,I assumed following for writing concreat code.

1. "source" is name of worksheet which contains the data to be copied
2. "destination" is name of worksheet which records tha data copied from "source" worksheet
3. Data to be copied is exist at "B2:F3" of worksheet "source"

Please change worksheets' names to real names of your data.

Place of data to be copied is described as "Range(sWS.Cells(2, 2), sWS.Cells(3, 6))" in the code.

cells(2,2) means cell on 2nd row and 2nd column, i.e. "B2".

Cells(3,6) means cell on 3rd row and 6th column, i.e. "F3".

Plese correct place to fit your data.